# when i trying to toggle a div my other dive are also toggled

Tags: jquery

> i am trying  to toggle  dive on click . but when i try to toggle onel others are also toggled.
>    i want a single code that work  for all div but on click only toggle the specified dive  not others.

```
My jquery Code:
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.more').click(function() {
                $('.read').slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
    $('.box').click(function (e) {
    $( '#' + $(this).data('toggleTarget') ).slideToggle(300);
});
    </script>

 i add the demo link here 
    [http://jsfiddle.net/20f2jkk7][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using class selector which will select all elements with the class `read`. Use `.nextAll('.read:first')` to get the desired div

```
 $('.more').click(function () {
     $(this).nextAll('.read:first').slideToggle("fast");
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/20f2jkk7/1/)

But i'd suggest putting each content in a div like this

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="more"></div>
  <div class="read"></div>
</div>
```

and then use .closest() to get the div, this will be more dynamic.

```
$(this).closest('.content').find('.read').slideToggle();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/20f2jkk7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have selected to toggle all the divs with `read` class on click of all the p with `more` class.

What you need to do is you need to use this to find out which one is clicked and then by traversing next and next find the div which should be toggled.

`$('.more').click(function () {
     $(this).next().next().slideToggle("fast");
 });`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `each` with `click` function for your code. That way each "more" button will output only it's respective indexed "read" content if all the content is in series... like an array that `each` will traverse.. Then in "read" selector, add eq(index) to specify the exact read-content element that occurs during traversing through "more" via `each`...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.more').each(function(index) {
            $(this).on("click", function(){
                $('.read:eq(' + index + ')').slideToggle("fast");
        });
        });
    });
    $('.box').click(function (e) {
    $( '#' + $(this).data('toggleTarget') ).slideToggle(300);
});
```

Here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/20f2jkk7/3/